# Raspberry Pi 3 KeDei 3.5" TFT LCD Version 6.0 driver problem

Tags: driver

3.5" TFT LCD Version 6.0, 480x320 display from eBay and try install on Raspberry Pi 3 using this tutorials http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A).

After instalation of this drivers my display start work after reboot but stack on boot and don't want to move.

I use drivers for raspbian-jessie LCD-show-160520.tar.gz

Can you help me?

Comment: Jus FYI, when installing the kernel "driver" it hooks up to the SPI port, so you need to disable SPI from raspi-config or it's gonna fail on boot.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the 3.5 inch LCD touch screen from kedei works with raspbian stretch. I have to use the latest driver at http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz

Initially, I followed some guide and installed a driver from earlier dates, it did not work. Then I installed this 6.1.3 driver and it showed some console text then went blank.

I gave it another try by starting from fresh raspbian stretch image, followed by this 6.1.3 driver. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The KeDei display and the Waveshare displays are two quite different things. You can read more about the KeDei and the differences (mostly disadvantages) to the WaveShare e.g. here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=124961

Comment: A little more detail in your answer would be great.

Comment: I need more details. I read that articles also find one web page with drivers for this display but that kill my Pi and I need over and over install new OS to start again.

Comment: More details than "these are two different devices"? Kedei is simply a different manufacturer than Waveshare. The KeDei drivers can be found at http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html The page i mentioned contains the most detailed information about the kedei display i know of.

Comment: From this link I try driver and don't want to boot also

Comment: I managed to get something working somehow. I also have a V6 board. I installed the contents of http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6/LCD_show_v6.tar.gz on top of the original raspbian from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2016-03-18/2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.zip. It initializes the display and displays a console on it. It even boots up to the desktop but it then gets stuck. But it's obvious from this already that the display is awful slow for the reasons explained under the link I posted before.

Comment: Also there's no source code of the driver. Thus you cannot use the current raspbian release as the binary only kernel with a matching driver included is already outdated. I'll try to get a refund for the display. It's close to useless ...

Comment: But if hardware is OK, wee need to find solution for software. Is not display slow, the probkem is inside driver

Answer (score 1):

For me the display works perfectly fine. The driver I use is LCD_show_v6_1_3 from http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html .

To install the driver just download the .tar-file, navigate the console to your extraction folder and command ". LCD35_v". The Raspberry will reboot and the display should work.

Comment: Will try thanks! Do you belive me, I not try anything a months, just keep display in box. Will try today.